# Assigning pointer into pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a set of pointers to image block objects. I have a derived class member function that returns a pointer to one of these image blocks, it is a virtual function so I can't change the return type without breaking everything.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ImageBlock* objArray = static_cast<ImageBlock*>( ::operator new ( sizeof ImageBlock * 256 ) );

for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
    new (&objArray[i]) ImageBlock(blkh, blkw, 0.0);

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        ImageBlock* temp = getNewBlock(i, j, Image); // getBlock returns ImageBlock*
        objArray[i*16 + j] = *temp;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

As you can see this is a terrible solution. I'd like to assign the pointer directly using some pointer arithmetic like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        (objArray+(i*16 + j)) = getNewBlock(i, j, Image);
    }
}
```

However I get the error `expression must be a modifiable lvalue` with `objArray` underlined in red. I know it would work the other way around taking a pointer from the array. I've searched the error and I keep seeing things like "you can't assign to arrays" well it isn't an array in the conventional sense is it? I have a few thoughts on why it won't work but I would like to know for sure. If anyone could offer up a better solution that would be interesting.

Thanks

Comment: `Ivalue`, you mean `lvalue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to assign pointers, you need to create an array of pointers. What you have is an array of `ImageBlock` objects, so the solution that you provided, i.e.

```
objArray[i*16 + j] = *temp;
```

is perfectly fine. If you would like to make an array of pointers, you need to declare and use it differently:

```
ImageBlock** objPtrArray = new ImageBlock*[256];
```

Now you can make an assignment using square bracket notation:

```
objPtrArray[i*16 + j] = getNewBlock(i, j, Image);
```

Of course it is now your responsibility to delete elements of `objArray`.

A better solution would be to use a vector of smart pointers. This would free you up from the chores of explicit memory management:

```
vector<unique_ptr<ImageBlock> > objVector(256);
...
objVector.push_back(unique_ptr<ImageBlock>(getNewBlock(i, j, Image)));
```

Comment: I used the double pointer notation. The project I'm doing is simple however I would prefer to learn more about memory management and the logic of it all. Using it definitely reduced the amount of code I had. Thank you, I will look into vectors if I have the time.